# how to Zooming in/zooming out of images in iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, animation, uiimageview, zooming

I want to give automatic zoom in and zoom out to image in ipad application. For example in the splash screen it should display image as original size and after some time it should start zooming out automatically. This will give it an animated zoom in/out look.

How can we do that with UIImageView in iPad?

Thank you in advance.

---

ScrollImageController.h

`@interface ScrollImageViewController : UIViewController  {`

}
@end

ScrollImageController.m

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{`

```
[super viewDidLoad];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]   initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(847, 800);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"just.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
[image release];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


[scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated: YES];
[scrollView release];
```

}

Comment: I think you mean how :-p

Answer (score 0):

You should make the UIImageView a subview of a UIScrollView

Then  make the class your using UIScrollViewDelegate, then use the following method.

```
    [MyScrollView setZoomScale:(float)scale animated:YES];
```

Edit: I don't think you need to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol

Comment: it does not work see the question for what i have done so far

Comment: Oh, sorry, this will work, however since you have this in the viewDidLoad method you don't see it zoom in, it just instantly zooms. If you would like to see what im talking about take the setZoomScale method out of the viewDidLoad method, and hook it up to a button with an IBAction. As far as your problem, i would recommend using NSTimer.

Comment: thanks for the help. Actually I had also thought of using NSTimer and it worked.